# How to solve inequality $1-\frac{1}{x}\geq 0$ correctly?

Tags: calculus, inequality

When I try to solve this inequality I get the wrong results:
$$1-\frac{1}{x}\geq 0$$
Assuming $x\neq 0$

It's really embarrassing that I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
So please help me, telling me where the maths goes wrong :D

---

$$1-\frac{1}{x}\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow 1\geq\frac{1}{x} \Leftrightarrow x\geq1$$

But this is wrong, since I can easily see $1-\frac{1}{x}\geq 0$ when x<0. So what am I doing wong?

Comment: Do you know wavy curve method ?

Comment: The mistake you are making is treating x positive . You don't flip the inequality sign when multiplying with a positive but you should reverse inequality if x is negative . Assume both cases that will give you the correct answer

Comment: You multiply by $x$ which may be negative and will flip the inequality sign. Multiply by $x^{2}$ instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, we have that

$$1-\frac{1}{x}\geq 0 \iff \frac1x\le 1$$

and

- for $x>0\quad x\cdot \frac1x\le x\cdot1 \implies x\ge 1$
- for $x<0\quad x\cdot \frac1x\ge x\cdot1  \implies x\le 1$ that is $x<0$

Also a graphical check for this simple inequality may help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's $$\frac{x-1}{x}\geq0,$$ which gives $$[1,+\infty)\cup(-\infty,0).$$

We used the intervals method.

In the expression $(x-a)^k$ the natural number $k$ is named a degree of the point $a$.

We need to solve
$$\frac{(x-1)^1}{(x-0)^1}\geq0.$$
The degree of $1$ is $1$ and the degree of $0$ is $1$.

If we go through a point $1$ so the sign of $x-1$ is changed because the degree of this point is odd.

If we go through a point $0$ so the sign of $x-0$ is changed because the degree of this point is odd.

For $x>1$ the expression $\frac{x-1}{x}$ has a sign $+$.

Thus, we obtain the following signs: $++++0----1++++$.

It's better to draw an $x$-axis and to put there points $0$ and $1$, which gives the following sequence of sings: $+$$-$$+$ and we obtain the answer: $[1,+\infty)\cup(-\infty,0).$

Another example.

Let we need to solve $\frac{(x-2)^2}{(x-1)(x-3)}\geq0.$

The degree of $2$ is even (the sign is not changed) and degrees of $1$ and $3$ are odds (the sign is changed).

Also, the sign of the expression  $\frac{(x-2)^2}{(x-1)(x-3)}$ for $x>3$ is $+$.

Thus, we have the following sequence of sings: $$+--+,$$ which gives the answer:
$$(-\infty,1)\cup(3,+\infty)\cup\{2\}$$

Comment: okay I see. 

But I think I need some rules about inequalities. Why is it I can't just add 1/x to both sides and multiply with x? Where do I lose information in that calculation?

What precautions should I take when working with inequalities?

Comment: @sjm23   This rule is  named an intervals method. The order of $1$ and of $0$ are odd, which says that the sign is changed.

Comment: Could you maybe link to some information about this. I have never heard about this arithmetic before. Which is kind of embarrassing, since I have taken multiple math courses at university so far :D It would be nice to know how to approach intervals in a more strict way.

Comment: @sjm23 I have no a link, but  I am ready to give some examples if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Set apart forbidden value $x=0$, you are with a quotient:

$$\dfrac{x-1}{x}>0$$

Here is a very convenient "recipe": the sign of the quotient $N/D$ is the same as the sign of the product $N*D=x(x-1)$.

As this product is a quadratic beginning with a positive coefficient for $x^2$, with real roots $0,1$, we can conclude that this product is $>0$ outside the interval $[0,1]$ delimited by these roots.

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong was the last double-implication.

In general, you can turn

$$
A \le C
$$
into
$$
AB \le CB
$$
*only* if you know that $B \ge 0$. When $B < 0$,
$$
A \le C
$$
is equivalent to
$$
AB \ge CB
$$
instead!

For example, we all agree that
$$
1 \le 4,
$$
right? Now multiply both sides by $-1$, and you get
$$
-1 ??? -4
$$
What should replace the "???" Answer: a $\ge$ sign, not a $\le$ sign!

Back to your equation. You had
$$
1 \ge \frac{1}{x} 
$$
and you wanted to multiply by $x$ ... but depending on whether $x$ is positive or negative, the result will be different.

So split into two cases: You say

"In the case where $x > 0$, this is equivalent to
$$
x \ge 1
$$
so we get, as solutions, all positive numbers greater than or equal to $1$.

In the case where we look for solutions $x$ with $x < 0$, our equation is equivalent (after multiplying both sides by $x$, a negative number!) to
$$
x \le 1.
$$
Of course, not all solutions of this equation satisfy our assumptions for this part of the work: numbers like $\frac{1}{2}$ are less than $1$, so they satisfy the equation, but they're not *negative*, so they don't satisfy the assumptions. Which negative numbers **are** less than or equal to $1$? All of them.

So the solutions overall are

1. All negative numbers, and
2. All positive numbers greater than or equal to $1$.