# Solving a super basic inequality

Tags: inequality

Can you please help me find where the problem arises in the solution?

> $1 + \frac{1}{x} \geq 0$

**My attempt:**

$1 + \frac{1}{x} \geq 0$

$1 \geq - \frac{1}{x}$

$x \geq -1$

The answer is $x \in (- \infty, -1] \bigcup (0, \infty)$.

---

I understand why the answer is so, but I made this mistake while solving a problem and didn't notice, so I want to understand how to approach problems like this.

Thanks!

Comment: If $a<0$ and $x < y $ then we have $ax > ay$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve inequality $1-\frac{1}{x}\geq 0$ correctly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831514/how-to-solve-inequality-1-frac1x-geq-0-correctly). The reasoning is exactly the same. Found using Approach0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying by a negative number *reverses* the inequality, so you need to consider the cases separately:

$$x\gt 0 \implies x\ge -1 \ \text{(this is always true)}\\ x\lt 0 \implies x\le -1 $$ by your second line and taking the intersection gives $x\gt 0$ or $x\le -1$.

Comment: I actually tried this, but didn't realize that because I get $x \geq -1$ when $x > 0$, I need to take $x >0$, thank you so much! Now everything is clear.

Comment: @AniKhachatryan :)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot just multiply by $x$ since it **can be negative** too. So, below is the right approach:
$$1 + \frac 1x \ge 0 \tag{$x\ne 0$} \\ \frac{x+1}{x} \ge 0 \iff x(x+1) \ge 0 \\\implies x \in (- \infty, -1] \cup (0, \infty)$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is negative, when you multiply on both sides of the equality by $x$ you would have to change the direction of the inequality. Avoid doing this when you don't know if $x$ is positive.